# How to correctly cascade delete secondary object from MongoDB when account is deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Users can create accounts on my app and are allowed to like, share X post.

The thing is that whenever a user deletes his/her account, everything related to them should also be deleted; so far I've been able to fix most of it but this:

```js
await this.model('Post').updateMany(
    {
      'sharedby.user': this._id
    },
    {
      $pull: { 'sharedby.user': this._id }
    }
  );
```

Obviously, I'm using dot notation since `user` is one of the objects found in the sharedby object from the `Post` model. Here it is:

```js
sharedby: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User'
        },
        post: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Post'
        }
      }
    ],
```

Whenever there's a `share`, this function gets triggered:

```js
const newshare = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.params.id,
      sharedby: { $ne: { user: req.user._id } }
    },
    {
      $push: { sharedby: { user: req.user._id, post: post._id } }
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      setDefaultsOnInsert: true
    }
  );
```

That's pretty much about it. I really have no idea why it's not working. Any suggestions? Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to delete all the matching records from `sharedby`, I imagine you'll want to use [`$pullAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/). Also, when using `$pull` or `$pullAll`, you should only use dot notation up to the Array boundary:

```js
await this.model('Post').updateMany(
  {
    'sharedby.user': this._id
  },
  {
    $pullAll: { 'sharedby': { user: this._id } }
  }
);
```

See also: [Remove Items from an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)